# Unity 5.3.4: Controlling multiple audio sources at once?

Tags: unity, audio

Is there a way to control the max distance of a group of audio sources at once? I want to implement all my sounds, then be able to play with some of the audiosource settings of all of them..

Comment: Would it work for you to create all your audio sources from a prefab and then change the max distance on the prefab?

Comment: Thinking about making a script I put on all audio sources and then changing the sources using that script